# ESP32 ADXL345 doesn't get the negative values

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

Hi I can run this code without any problem on Arduino UNO. My output is like : `0.05  0.10  1.01`
But when I run this code on ESP32, my output is : `255.89  255.81  0.99` and I don't see any minus value. What is the problem?
ESP32's X,Y,Z raw values like : `6500 0 , 65000 , 1` . ESP32 can't get the negative values. I have to do something with wire.h and I need to change uint8_t or uint16_t something but I really don't understand how should I solve this problem.

```
#include <Wire.h>  // Wire library - used for I2C communication
int ADXL345 = 0x53; // The ADXL345 sensor I2C address
float X_out, Y_out, Z_out;  // Outputs
float X, Y, Z ;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // Initiate serial communication for printing the results on the Serial monitor
  Wire.begin(); // Initiate the Wire library
  // Set ADXL345 in measuring mode
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // Start communicating with the device
  Wire.write(0x31);
  Wire.write(0x0B);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x20); // Z-axis offset register
  Wire.write(-7);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x2D); // Access/ talk to POWER_CTL Register - 0x2D
  // Enable measurement
  Wire.write(0x08); // (8dec -> 0000 1000 binary) Bit D3 High for measuring enable
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x2C);
  // Enable measurement
  Wire.write(0x09); //For low power 000x x pin set to 1  /1001 determine Hz
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}
void loop() {
  unsigned long Time = millis();
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x32); // Start with register 0x32 (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  X_out = ( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8); // X-axis value
  X = X_out /256; //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 256, according to the datasheet
  Y_out = ( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8); // Y-axis value
  Y = Y_out /256;
  Z_out = ( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8); // Z-axis value
  Z = Z_out /256;
  delay(20);
  Serial.print(X);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Y);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(Z);
  Serial.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: `int` on an Uno is 16-bit, on ESP32 it's 32-bit. Why don't you use a library that should handle that properly for you?

Comment: @gre_gor I want to use every value similar to UNO because I am using ESP32 for testing uno. That's why I don't want to use any library (I will send datas to client with esp32).

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome This code you are using is broken (even on UNO). Beyond the different size of ints it just works by chance. The execution order of `( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8)` is not defined. Therefore you could get different interpretations even in the same binary.

Comment: @m2j I took it from here [howtomechatronics.com](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-track-orientation-with-arduino-and-adxl345-accelerometer/) . He has video on youtube 233 B views. I though it is true and that's why I used it.  I also used this on C with stm. ı wrote it like `data_rec[1]<<8 | data_rec[0] ` is this the correct ?

Comment: Instead of using `Int` which is platform dependent. Use `int16_t` if you need it for cross-platform consistency.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome accessing both indices of the array in one call is no problem. You do not know the execution order but the result is well defined in any case. In contrast to `Wire.read()`: here the result differs whether the compiler chooses to start with the left or the right call. I just looked to your source. They are doing it wrong. Store the first and the second byte in intermediate variables and join them afterwards. Best you write a small function to do this (e.g. readInt16()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the Arduino Uno there are **16-bit integers**. The ADXL345 seems to receive this data format. Therefore everything plays out nicely. You are using **32-bit integers** on the ESP32. Therefore you have to choose the right data type explicitly. Otherwise the negative numbers appear in the positive region.
2. The **execution order** of the `Wire.read()`-calls is not defined in your code. Therefore the compiler may join the bytes `0xAA` and `0xBB` to `0xAABB` or `0xBBAA`. You should add a sequence point to make sure that the code does what's intended.

I have not tested this code. That should be the correct order, in case I got the datasheet description right:

```
int16_t readInt16()
{
    int lsb = Wire.read();
    int msb = Wire.read();
    return int16_t(lsb | msb << 8);
}

X_out = readInt16() / 256.f;
Y_out = readInt16() / 256.f;
Z_out = readInt16() / 256.f;
```

Comment: Thank you @m2j, I already changed my code after you told me but I couldn't get the float value. After this comment I added '256.f' now it is working.